# extjs4 get selected value from combobox

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

Ok, this is driving me nuts again. I am trying to get the selected value from a combo box so I can update a grid with the correct data based on the user selection. How do I do this?

I am using extjs 4 in MVC model. Here is my code:

my init inside the viewport:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'viewport > combobox': {
            select: this.onChangeStacker
        }
    });
},

// method with pseudocode of what I want to do
onChangeStacker: function(){

    selected =  getSelection;


   switch selected

    case == stk1

         load stk1

    case == stk2 

         load stkd
}
});
```

Comment: Is your combobox a direct descendant of viewport? And, don't forget to accept the answer given by CD..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.control({
    'viewport > combobox': {
        change: function(cmp) {
            var value = cmp.getValue();
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
});​
```

Documentation:

- [getValue method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-getValue)
- [change event](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-event-change)

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kMs86/